# CustomView Listener(Callback) with multiple button and different id

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a **SlideButton Library** everything is almost complete but there is a problem in **onClickListener**
The problem is when i use **customView(i.e SlideButton)** in xml **two or more times with different id** and **implement that Listener in MainActivity**

So the problem is that only one **SlideButton(i.e slideButton1) is called when i click on any button** even i am comparing button with id like **if(slideButton1.getId()==R.id.btnUp)** but nothing happen.

**In short i am using CustomView multiple time in xml with different id and use in MainActivity then only one button is called always**

**Here is my CustomView class**

```
public class SlideButton extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView centerText;
    ImageButton slidingButton;

    TypedArray typedArray;
    //shapes
    GradientDrawable buttonCollapse,buttonExpand,backgroundButton;
    String mAttrText;
    Drawable disabledDrawable,enabledDrawable;
    int mAttrId,mAttrButtonPadding,mAttrTextPadding,
            mAttrTextSize,mAttrTextColor,mAttrRadius,mAttrCollapse,
            mAttrStrokeWidth,mAttrStrokeColor,mAttrExpand,mAttrBackColor,
            mAttrBackStrokeColor,mAttrBackStrokeWidth;

    //it is the variable that says that the button is expand or not.
    private boolean active;
    //it is the initial width of the button. we need to save it so we can back to the initial position.
    private int initialButtonWidth;
    SlideListener listener;

    public SlideButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context,null,-1,-1);
    }

    public SlideButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, -1, -1);
    }

    public SlideButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, -1);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public SlideButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {

        attrValue(context,attrs);
        btnCollapse();
        btnExpand();
        backButton();
        dynamicLayout(context);
        dynamicButton(context);
        dynamicTextView(context);
        new ShineEffect(centerText);

        try {
            listener = (SlideListener) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
  -----------------------------------------getting attr values---------------------------------------------------------
     */
    private void attrValue(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){

        typedArray=context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.SlideButton,0,0);
        try {

            //attribute for text
            mAttrText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SlideButton_text);
            mAttrTextPadding=typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_textPadding,0);
            mAttrTextSize=typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_textSize,0);
            mAttrTextColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_textColor, Color.GRAY);

            //attribute for  button
            mAttrButtonPadding =typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_buttonPadding,0);
            mAttrRadius=typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_cornerRadius,45);
            mAttrCollapse=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_collapseColor,Color.WHITE);
            mAttrExpand=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_expandColor,Color.WHITE);
            disabledDrawable=typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SlideButton_collapseIcon);
            enabledDrawable=typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.SlideButton_expandIcon);
            mAttrStrokeColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_strokeColor,Color.parseColor("#ee071a32"));
            mAttrStrokeWidth=typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_strokeWidth,3);

            //attribute for background
            mAttrBackColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_backColor,Color.parseColor("#ee071a32"));
            mAttrBackStrokeColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SlideButton_backStrokeColor,Color.WHITE);
            mAttrBackStrokeWidth=typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SlideButton_backStrokeWidth,3);
        }
        finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    /*
  -----------------------------------------btn collapse shape---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void btnCollapse(){
        buttonCollapse = new GradientDrawable();
        buttonCollapse.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        buttonCollapse.setCornerRadius(mAttrRadius);
        buttonCollapse.setColor(mAttrCollapse);
        buttonCollapse.setStroke(mAttrStrokeWidth,mAttrStrokeColor);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------btn expand shape---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void btnExpand(){
        buttonExpand = new GradientDrawable();
        buttonExpand.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        buttonExpand.setCornerRadius(mAttrRadius);
        buttonExpand.setColor(mAttrExpand);
        buttonExpand.setStroke(mAttrStrokeWidth,mAttrStrokeColor);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------btn background shape---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void backButton(){
        backgroundButton = new GradientDrawable();
        backgroundButton.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        backgroundButton.setCornerRadius(mAttrRadius);
        backgroundButton.setColor(mAttrBackColor);
        backgroundButton.setStroke(mAttrBackStrokeWidth,mAttrBackStrokeColor);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------dynamic linear layout---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void dynamicLayout(Context context) {
        linearLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
        //LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how big the view wants to be for both in width and height
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setBackground(backgroundButton);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        //add the view to parent layout
        addView(linearLayout);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------dynamic text view---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void dynamicTextView(Context context) {
        centerText=new TextView(context);
        centerText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        centerText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        centerText.setText(mAttrText);
        centerText.setPadding(mAttrTextPadding,0,0,0);
        centerText.setTextSize(mAttrTextSize);
        centerText.setTextColor(mAttrTextColor);
        linearLayout.addView(centerText);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------dynamic image button--------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void dynamicButton(Context context) {
       slidingButton=new ImageButton(context);
       LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
       slidingButton.setLayoutParams(params);
       slidingButton.setId(mAttrId);
       slidingButton.setImageDrawable(disabledDrawable);
       slidingButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
       slidingButton.setPadding(mAttrButtonPadding,mAttrButtonPadding,mAttrButtonPadding,mAttrButtonPadding);
       slidingButton.setBackground(buttonCollapse);
       linearLayout.addView(slidingButton);
       slidingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------listener---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(active){
            collapseButton();
        }
        else {
            initialButtonWidth=slidingButton.getWidth();
            expandButton();
        }
    }

    public interface SlideListener{
        void onClick(boolean active);
    }

    public void setOnSlideListener(SlideListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------expand animation---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void expandButton()
    {
        final ValueAnimator widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(slidingButton.getWidth(),getWidth()-6);
        widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
            {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = slidingButton.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = (Integer) widthAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                slidingButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                slidingButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        widthAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                active = true;

                if (listener!=null) {
                    listener.onClick(true);
                }
                slidingButton.setEnabled(true);
                slidingButton.setImageDrawable(enabledDrawable);
                slidingButton.setBackground(buttonExpand);
            }
        });
        widthAnimator.start();
    }

     /*
  -----------------------------------------collapse animation---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void collapseButton() {

        final ValueAnimator widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(slidingButton.getWidth(), initialButtonWidth);
        widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
            {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =  slidingButton.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = (Integer) widthAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                slidingButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                slidingButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        widthAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                active = false;

                if(listener!=null){
                    listener.onClick(false);
                }
                slidingButton.setEnabled(true);
                if(disabledDrawable!=null){
                    slidingButton.setImageDrawable(disabledDrawable);
                }
                slidingButton.setBackground(buttonCollapse);
            }
        });
        widthAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

**here is xml using custom view**

```
<com.greenlab.hackme.slidebutton.SlideButton
        android:id="@+id/btnUp"

        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        custom:buttonPadding="20dp"
        custom:cornerRadius="45dp"
        custom:collapseColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:expandColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapsed"
        custom:expandIcon="@drawable/expanded"
        custom:strokeColor="#ee071a32"
        custom:strokeWidth="3dp"
        custom:backStrokeColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:backColor="#ee071a32"
        custom:backStrokeWidth="2dp"
        custom:text="Tap to Activate"
        custom:textPadding="20dp"
        custom:textSize="8dp"
        custom:textColor="#a39c9c">
    </com.greenlab.hackme.slidebutton.SlideButton>

    <com.greenlab.hackme.slidebutton.SlideButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDown"

        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        custom:buttonPadding="15dp"
        custom:cornerRadius="25dp"
        custom:collapseColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:expandColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapsed"
        custom:expandIcon="@drawable/expanded"
        custom:strokeColor="#ee071a32"
        custom:strokeWidth="3dp"

        custom:backStrokeColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:backColor="#ee071a32"
        custom:backStrokeWidth="2dp"

        custom:text="Tap to Activate"
        custom:textPadding="20dp"
        custom:textSize="8dp"
        custom:textColor="#b3a9a9">
    </com.greenlab.hackme.slidebutton.SlideButton>
```

**Here is MainActivity implement listener**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SlideButton.SlideListener {

    SlideButton slideButton1,slideButton2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        slideButton1=findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        slideButton2=findViewById(R.id.btnDown);

        slideButton1.setOnSlideListener(this);
        slideButton2.setOnSlideListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(boolean active) {

        if(slideButton1.getId()==R.id.btnUp) {

            if(active){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Active Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Deactivate Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if(slideButton2.getId()==R.id.btnDown){

            if(active){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Active Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Deactivate Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**here is attribute.xml file**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SlideButton">

        <attr name="text" format="string"/>
        <attr name="textPadding" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="textColor" format="color"/>

        <attr name="buttonPadding" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="collapseColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="expandColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="collapseIcon" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="expandIcon" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="strokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="strokeColor" format="color"/>

        <attr name="backStrokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="backStrokeColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="backColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the callback `interface` like this:

```
public interface SlideListener {
    void onClick(SlideButton button, boolean active);
}
```

And everywhere in `SlideButton` class call the `onClick` with passing current reference:

```
if (listener != null) {
    listener.onClick(SlideButton.this, true/false);
}
```

Then in `MainActivity` check the id of clicked button as following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(SlideButton button, boolean active) {

    if(button.getId() == R.id.btnUp) {
        if(active){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Active Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Deactivate Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if(button.getId() == R.id.btnDown) {
        if(active){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Active Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Deactivate Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are great dear its working..:)   Thanks a lot to you and Stackoverflow

Comment: if you do not mind please tell me how to be great like you in android so that i can also help on Stackoverflow again thanks..

Comment: You're welcome dude:) You are great in android just now, your code in SlideButton is good, mistakes always happens. If you keep on writing codes, you'll see that the other's problems is solvable by you, soon.